# SQL Server query to reduce numbers in a specific column by X %?

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to ask you guys how I can reduce numbers above +100,000 from specific column in SQL Server 2005 by X % via query ? I've searched around but didn't found a right way to do it.

I'll give you an example: in database `OnlineGame` I've got a table `Monsters` and in that table there is a column of monsters' HP ... so, I want to lower all monsters that have +100,000 HP by X % ? Will be a much appreciated if that's possible to be done.

To sum it up in a few words: All monsters that have 100,000+ HP to be lowered by X % in a specific column in that table.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reduce by 10%:

```
UPDATE Monsters SET HP = HP * 0.9 WHERE HP > 100000;
```

I'm sure you can figure out how to reduce by other percentages from here.

Comment: So, this query will reduce(not make it higher) all monsters HP that have 100000+ HP by 10 % ? I am asking to make sure thats correct because I will screw it in that case .. and its big db .. will take a lot to restore it. It won't touch if they have lower HP ...

Comment: If you want to verify the result run it as a select first: `SELECT HP AS Before, HP * 0.9 AS After, * FROM Monsters WHERE HP > 100000;`

Comment: It works but it makes them like that if the HP was 100000 after the query it goes like 90000.0 ... ?

Is there a way to make them without .0 at the end ? Also, i saw a ihppoint for example 109209.7 ... :OOOO there must be no .X numbers just plain numbers.

Comment: If the column is an `int` to begin with it will automatically be converted (the fraction truncated) in the update.

Comment: Is there a way to ignore this .X number when it updates it via this query you specified ?

Comment: It is automatically ignored/fixed when you put it back in the `int` field with the update. Please learn the basics of programming before worrying too much about this, and just execute the query. It works.

Comment: I got it but I am not sure that its int only thats why ... a way to check it out ?

Comment: If it's *not* an `int` the programmers intended it like that, so it doesn't matter. If it's not even numeric the query would've failed, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: So, it doesn't matter if it's int or not .. it will directly ignore the .X number when updating it ?

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant the previous 3 times when I said it would be ignored, truncated and automatically fixed.

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '300000.1' to data type int. that's the error i've got when tried to update one manualy with .x number at the end.

Comment: You were right. It updated it without the .X numbers ... just last thing because I am really curious .. why it actually ignored it .X number at the end ? Much appreciated. How to rate your answer buddy ?

Comment: When you use a `double` value (so with fraction like `6.84`) as an `int` nearly every programming language, including SQL, will silently and implicitly convert it by truncation the fraction so only `6` remains. And I'll be happy again if you hit the 'accept' checkmark left of the answer  ;)

Comment: I will do it and lastly I updated my int HP column, but now I see that I should update defpoint column as well which still contains numbers but its smallint .. can i still use your query or there will be a problem since its smallint ?

Comment: Query will work exactly the same, not sure what's in there though since a `smallint` cannot contain values of 100000.

Comment: Yeah, its for defpoint column ... they are always less than 30000 .. so, lastly to make sure - It doesn't allow decimals just like int and will ignore the .X just exactly as int ? The only difference between int and smallint is that it cant accept numbers higher than 100000 ?

Comment: A `smallint` is just an `int` with a reduced range (-32768 to 32767).

Comment: I see. So, I'll have no problems using the above query for smallint as well. Now I've learned another thing, lol. int and smallint will always truncate the fraction at the end of the number, correctly ? Basically this cannot screw up the column by adding .X numbers. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
update monsters set monsters.hp = monsters.hp * x where monsters.hp > 100000;
```

Comment: ha, that was quick work!  Yeah, sorry had rails migrations polluting my brain.  Realized it looked funny and posted revision and it had already been called out.  Gotta love net speed.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE MONSTERS SET HP = HP * (1-X) WHERE HP > 100,000
```

Wrap that in a Procedure that takes x as an input variabll. You also may want to convert the limiting value (100,000) to another variable.

Comment: they are without , just plain numbers 1000000 ... just gave that as an example.

Comment: my comma is just to make it legible here. You would not include that in the code.

Comment: (1-X) so 1 state for 100 % ? and it will become 1-0.9 to lower them by 10 % ?

Comment: If you want to reduce by 10% then X would be 0.1 (10% represented as a decimal)
(1 - X) then becomes 0.9 or 90% which is what you want the result to be after the update.

Comment: Yeah, got it. But after I did to check the query:
select HP * (1-0.1) from monsters where hp > 100000   
I received numbers like 270000.0 or 108209.7 ... is there a way so when the db updates it via this query it will ignore the .X numbers and update it only in plain numbers like 108209 without the 7 at the end ?

Comment: Just round the result
`UPDATE MONSTERS SET HP = ROUND(HP * (1-X),0) WHERE HP > 100000`

Comment: It makes them all to be number.0 at the end ?

Comment: yes, it rounds to 0 decimal places.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '300000.0' to data type int. that's the error i've got when tried to update one manualy with .x number at the end. So, is there basically a way to just remove all .X at the end in the query itself like the round make them 0 but actually remove it ?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column that you are trying to update?

Comment: How I can check the datatype of the specific column ?

Comment: Actually i tried editing it by hand that's why i received this error above. Also, is there a difference from int and smallint ? because my hp point column is smallint, so will your query still works and ignore .X numbers ?

Comment: Here is an explicit conversion to a SmallInt
`UPDATE MONSTERS SET HP = CONVERT(SMALLINT,ROUND(HP * (1-X),0)) WHERE HP > 100000`

Comment: And this will convert the numbers to fit smallint or what exactly this convert smallint do ?

Comment: Dude, you need to take some time to learn the basics of database design. Have you read the definition of the CONVERT function? Do you know what different datatypes mean?